# Convergence of 1 over sine serie, a hard one

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

I want to find the radius of this series, I tried my best I proved that r<1.
$$ \sum _ { n = 1 } ^ \infty \frac { x ^ n } { \sin ( n \theta ) } $$
is convergent for $ \theta = t \pi $ such that $ t $ is irrational, e.g.  $ \theta = \sqrt 3 \pi $.

It is a really interesting question because it will tell something about how the $ \sin \left( \sqrt 3 \pi n \right)$ goes to zero for some sequence goes to infinity (since $ \sqrt 3 $ is irrational sin will have a dense image in $ [ 0 , 1 ] $).P

Comment: I would be surprised that $x^n>\sin n\theta$ does not hold infinitely many times for $x>0$.

Comment: @Yves_Daoust There is a necessary condition if the series converges, then $lim \frac{x^n}{sin(n\theta)} \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$, this is true in most cases when $sin(n\theta)$ converges to a number different than 0. But which one will dominate if  $sin(n\theta)$  goes to 0.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You would be surprised, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

$r=1$ for $t=\sqrt3$ and pretty much any other number you've ever heard of.
Then there are just as many "bad" numbers for which $r<1$ and can be anything, all the way down to $0$.

**Now come the details.**

[Roth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth%27s_theorem) basically says that an algebraic number $\alpha$ can't be approximated by the rationals "too well" - that is, $\left|\alpha-{\frac {p}{q}}\right|>\frac1{q^{2+\varepsilon}}$ for all but finitely many $\frac pq$. With that in mind, we have:

$$\left|{1\over\sin n\theta}\right|=\left|{1\over\sin(n\theta-p\pi)}\right| \leqslant{\pi/2\over|n\theta-p\pi|}={n\cdot const\over\left|{\theta\over\pi}-{p\over n}\right|}\leqslant n^{3+\varepsilon}\cdot const$$

and of course the series $\sum x^nn^4$ (here I chose $\varepsilon=1$) has the radius of convergence equal to $1$.

The same goes for all other numbers with finite [irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure).

Now the "bad" part. One can construct numbers with *infinite* irrationality measure, and they (though not even all of them) can make our radius a bit shorter. Say we have $x={1\over2}$; to break the convergence, we need $\left|{1\over\sin n\theta}\right|>2^n$ for infinitely many $n$. Can that be done? Why, that's easy. We know that for the [continued fraction convergents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) of $\alpha$, $\left|\alpha-{p_n\over q_n}\right|<{1\over q_nq_{n+1}}$. Well, just make that $q_{n+1}$ bigger. How big can it be made? As big as you wish and even bigger. Can it be greater than $2^{q_n}$? Sure, and the extra topping is on the house.

So it goes.

Comment: @ivan_Neretin thank you very much for all the facts you provided. I had one issue in the first inequality, how we pass from $\frac{1}{|sin(n\theta - p\pi)|} \leq \frac{\pi/2}{|n\theta - p\pi|}$

Comment: Well, $\sin x\geqslant{2\over\pi}x$ for $0\leqslant x\leqslant{\pi\over2}$, isn't it?

Comment: @iven_Neretin yep it is i checked it. Again thanks a lot for your time. Kind regards

Comment: Then consider _accepting_ my answer.

Comment: I am new to this website but i think i accepted it.

Comment: Good.$\mathstrut$